# Can anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong in this. Not able to get values back on component from js controller. Please help

Tags: aura

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="BeerSearchController" >
    <aura:attribute type="object" name="accList" />
    <div class="slds-p-horizontal_x-small"><lightning:input name="Search" placeholder="Please Search Here" type="search" aura:id ="searchid" />
        <lightning:button label="Submit" onclick="{!c.SearchBeers}" />
    </div>
    <div>
        {!v.accList.Name}
    </div>
    </aura:component>
```

js controller:

```
({
    SearchBeers : function(component, event, helper) {
        var typedval = component.find("searchid"); 
        var searchval = typedval.get("v.value");
        var action = component.get("c.BeerSearchController");
        action.setParams({
            searchString : searchval
        })
        action.setCallback(this,function(data){
          var state = data.getState(); 
          var returnval = data.getReturnValue();
          alert(JSON.stringify(returnval));
          component.set("v.accList",data.getReturnValue());
        });
       $A.enqueueAction(action);  
    }
})
```

apex class:

```
public class BeerSearchController {
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<Account> BeerSearchController(String searchString){
               
        list<Account> accList = new list<Account>();
        String j= '%'+searchString+'%';
        accList = [select id,name from Account where name like :j];
        return accList;
        
        
    }
      
        
        
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not bind list attribute directly with out using [aura iteration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:iteration/example) .

```
<aura:component controller="BeerSearchController" >
        <aura:attribute type="object" name="accList" />
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal_x-small"><lightning:input name="Search" placeholder="Please Search Here" type="search" aura:id ="searchid" />
            <lightning:button label="Submit" onclick="{!c.SearchBeers}" />
        </div>
        <div>
    <aura:iteration items=”{!v.accList}” var=”acc” indexVar=”key”>
       {!acc.Name}
    </aura:iteration>
            
        </div>
        </aura:component>
```